# VS Code doesn't open a terminal

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I recently updated windows to version Windows 10 22H2. After that the terminal in VS Code stopped working. I'm trying to open it, but system gives an error: "The terminal process failed to launch: Access was denied to the path containing your executable "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe". Manage and change your permissions to get this to work." I already visited the help from VS Code itself, but didn't find what I need. Powershell.exe is present in the folder that the program shows me. Maybe it's the version of Windows or the shell itself, because it was different before. Maybe I need to go into VS Code settings to change something, because I see a couple of settings that I didn’t change, however they changed?
Thanks in advance for your help!
Attaching the necessary screenshots.

Powershell:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7cw0.png)

Settings:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ym2H.png)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541, https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson